# PHP cURL not working for sending POST request to api

Tags: php, api, curl, post

I am trying to send post request to a SMS api and receive the feedback from them using PHP and cURL .But, the cURL is not working for me ,when i try to send the same data through form it works.

```
$POST = array(
            'data' => $xml1

    );
$url = 'URL';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $POST );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo "<input type=\"textarea\" id=\"txt\"  style='width:600px' value='$result'></input>";
echo "<input type=\"textarea\" id=\"txt1\" name='data1' style='width:600px' value='".$info['request_header']."'></input>";
```

And the XML IS

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE MESSAGE SYSTEM "http://127.0.0.1:80/psms/dtd/messagev12.dtd">
<MESSAGE VER="1.2">
<USER USERNAME="abc" PASSWORD="pqr" />
<SMS UDH="0" CODING="1" TEXT="SMS TEXT" PROPERTY="0" ID="1" TEMPLATE="" EMAILTEXT="" ATTACHMENT=""><ADDRESS FROM="someone" TO="91xxxxxxxxxx" EMAIL="" SEQ="1" TAG="some clientside random data"/>
</SMS>
</MESSAGE>
```

BUT USING FORM IT WORKS FINE ,CODE FOR FORM

```
echo "<form action=\"URL\" method=\"POST\" target=\"_blank\">";

    echo "<input type=\"textarea\" id=\"txt\" name='data' style='width:600px' value='$xml1'></input>";
    echo "<input type=\"SUBMIT\" name=\"action\" value=\"send\">";
    echo "</form>";
```

When I send data using form it shows Sent status but when i send using curl it shows output as :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <MESSAGEACK>
    <Err Code="65535" Desc="The Specified message does not conform to DTD"/>
</MESSAGEACK>
```

Thanks

Comment: First difference I can see is that you are missing `"action" => "send"` in the curl `$POST` data. Your curl version also sets the request `content-type` header to "multipart/form-data"

Comment: @Phil I changed the content type to text/xml and added action = send ,but still its showing the same error

Comment: The `<form>` version would set the content-type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, not `text/xml`

Comment: Try to set `SSL_VERIFYPEER` to `false` like `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);`

Comment: @Phil tried that no luck

Comment: @GokulShinde its not working either

Comment: So what does the DTD look like?

Comment: @Phil I dont have any access to DTD , I am new to this ,am I doing some mistake in designing array ? ..coz it worked fine when i sent using form

Comment: Only other thing I can think of is that putting the XML into an `<input>` will strip out all the newline characters. Perhaps try making your XML all on one line with no leading or trailing spaces and no whitespace between the tags. Also, if you're setting the `content-type` header, make sure you do that **after** you set the post-fields

Comment: @Phil the spaces and tags are perfect ..I think the problem is in the array I send ,i even tried  {curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "data =".$xmlcontent."action=send" );}

Comment: @AkshayWani have you tried it with using POSTMAN ?

Answer (score 1):

instead of creating array.

```
$POST = array('data' => $xml1);
```

Simply do `$POST => $xml1`

Answer (score 0):

How did you set `$xml1` variable?

Make sure you used `$xml1 = file_get_contents($xmlFilepath)` istead of `simplexml_load_file($xmlFilepath)`

Comment: i generated xml dynamically using php and mysql so `$xml1` is just a variable containing xml

Comment: So, `$xml1` data type is SimpleXMLElement object or string?

Comment: its string not SimpleXMLElement Object

Comment: try this line: `{curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "data=".$xml1."&action=send" );}` .